# Need some help trying get this sticky footer just right

Tags: css, push, margin, footer, sticky

Website in question: http://www.flowersbe.com

So I am not having an issue getting the footer to stick to the bottom, my issue is that I have a top margin on my container that pushes the footer down 25px past the bottom of the browser, which is most evident on the contact page of the above site. I want to keep the 25px space at the top but I still want the footer to be fully visible...below is my css for the container and the footer...any ideas on how I can resolve this issue?

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    width: 960px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 25px auto -50px;
    background-color: #fff;
}


footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 960px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    background-color: #ffebeb;
    text-align: center;
}

.push {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to achieve exactly what you want to do, you would have to introduce some JavaScript to calculate the exact height that `#container` should be.

It is translating the `height` of 100% to the exact height of the viewport, then adding the 25px margin on top of that. The only way I can think of to get around that is to use JavaScript to get the height of the viewport and set the height of `#container` to that value minus 25px.

Possible alternate solutions that don't involve JS:

- Just drop the `min-height` and allow `#container` to be only as tall as it needs to be.
- Use `position: fixed` on the `footer` to ensure that the footer is always at the bottom of the viewport, but note that it would sit on top of any content long enough to go beyond the height of the viewport.

Does that give you enough to go on?

Comment: Thanks Scott, I'll give it a go and see what I come up with.